# Master-Detail relationship in design tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, database-design, master-detail

I need to create 2 tables rosters and records, whereby each roster has many records. 
A roster is based on class and there is maximum 1 roster for each class per day.
A record can have many students.

I wonder that this **master-detail** relationship design is effective?
My friend suggests that everything could be done in record table, since we want to display a roster of all the students in a class in a specific day. So in the master-detail approach, it takes query on **2 tables** to accomplish the task, in contrast, it take only **1 query** if there is only one record table.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

If you have attributes of `ROSTER` that you need to track over and above a primary key value, then database normalization rules require you to split out the `ROSTER` table.  Of course, you can always choose to denormalize, but that decision must be made with your eyes wide open.

If you *don't* have columns for `ROSTER` other than a key, then your friend is right.  Otherwise you should remind your friend that just because something *could* be done, doesn't mean it *should* be done.